# How prevent editText add "." if initialized to accept float values only?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

`editText` initialized to accept float values as following

**EditText in Xml**

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    style="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat"
    android:hint="enter value"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:theme="@style/dialog_blue_button" />
```

i want prevent input = "." as follow

**onClick event where user add input**

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.ok) {
        String text = edit.getText().toString();
        if (!text.matches("") && !text.matches(".")) {

            float s = Float.parseFloat(edit.getText().toString());
            if (s > 0) {
                communicator.input(s);
                dismiss();
            }
        }
    } else {
        dismiss();
    }

}
```

**problem**
this code prevent user enter single integer for example 1 or 8 not accepted but 12 accepted

Comment: . matches every character try \\. To really match a dot

Comment: Do you want that in your `EditText` don't contains a dot?

Comment: i want edittext not to accept dot if dot is the only input

Comment: But you want to accept and EditText like "Hello." ?

Comment: look at xml file it only accept numberDecimal

Comment: it cannot accept Strings

Comment: See my answer below, let me see if it did something different

Comment: because it accept float user can add #.#  so i want prevent dot if dot is the only input

Comment: if (!text.isEmpty() && !text.matches("^\\.$")) or replace the second one with !".".equals(text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
if (!text.isEmpty() && !text.matches("^\\.$"))
```

`^\\. $`
The `^` indicates the beginning of a String. Since `.` is a special char and will match any character you have to escape it with `\\`. 
The `$` indicates the end of the String. This regex will only match a String which consists of only a dot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this insted of your code :

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      if (v.getId() == R.id.ok) {
          String text = edit.getText().toString();
          if (!text.equals("") && !text.equals(".")) {

              float s = Float.parseFloat(edit.getText().toString());
              if (s > 0) {
                  communicator.input(s);
                  dismiss();
              }
          }
      } else {
          dismiss();
      }

  }
```

Comment: i tried these one before it crash my app if input is only dot

Comment: Show me the LogCat please

Comment: it crash app if  if_statement look like if (!text.equals(""))....in code above it does not accept dot and one integer like 1 or 4 but 44 accepted

Comment: 08-27 22:52:55.292: E/AndroidRuntime(20796): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 22:52:55.292: E/AndroidRuntime(20796): Process: developer.mohab.gymee, PID: 20796
08-27 22:52:55.292: E/AndroidRuntime(20796): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
08-27 22:52:55.292: E/AndroidRuntime(20796):  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
08-27 22:52:55.292: E/AndroidRuntime(20796):  at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:176)
08-27 22:52:55.292: E/AndroidRuntime(20796):

Comment: You didn't put anything on the `EditText` now?

Comment: i added only dot  "."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88132/discussion-between-error-and-skizo).